# Delphi: AV after exit Delphi 6

Tags: delphi, exception, package, exit

Not too long ago my Delphi 6 prof has worked well (1-2 months?).

But now it is generate an AV on exit (EListError in rtl60, it is uses [0] index).

I don't know where I search the source of the error. And how to do it...?

Many packages we have (for example the AlphaSkin is what many times generating errors).

Do you have any idea to see what is the problematic component, or package, or extension (GExpert) that cause the error?

Do you have any idea to don't deinstalling all packages one-by-one?

Comment: D6 is just like that in my experience. Later versions do it too.

Comment: I would go with a new VM in which you install packages one by one until you get the error, also save a list of installs and stuff, I believe that the IDE is bloated with third party components and experts, wouldn't be surprised in two of them don't play well together...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Practically every single error on shutdown of the IDE is the result of a wayward plugin, component, or IDE Expert.

Have you added new components or experts lately?

The way to track it down is to

1. Remove Something
2. Shutdown
3. Repeat until no error occurs
4. The last
   thing removed was the culprit.

No fun I know, but that's what you have to do.

Comment: The JCL was the problematic thing! Interesting that JCL setup always crashing my machine (Win7/x64, D6). I installed it in "decreased" (not normal) mode of OS. But as I see it causes problem.

Comment: @nick the modern versions of the ide can manage to crash without help from third parties....

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - my D2009 usually survives the 'normal' intervals between Windows Update reboots.

Answer (score 2):

I have had great success finding the cause of these normal exceptions (i.e. not AVs) by installing [madExcept](http://madshi.net/madExceptDescription.htm) **into the IDE**. It will give you a full call stack once the exception occurs, so the cause can most likely be identified just from that.